# How do I return back to RootView Controller from my last view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios10

I have 5 view controller and want to come back from the last view to 1st view controller

Comment: Please start by taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), then learn to create an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consult your [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this method on Animation splash screen

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

-(void) setHidden:(id)sender
{
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboare" bundle:nil];
     YourVC* vController = (YourVC*)[Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardId"];
     UINavigationController *navcotoller=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vController];
     self.window.rootViewController =navcotoller;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a function in which you have to change the app rootviewcontroller. set it as a navigationController

```
yourViewcontoller *viewController = [[yourViewContoller alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards, give the UINavigationController a Storyboard ID. You can then initiate it and present through the code:

```
UINavigationController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<Storyboard ID>"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UINavigationController` you could and should simply call

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```